# is it possible to change the colors on parts of an image using jquery, css, etc

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, colors

i have an image that shows different fireworks.  I want to make the colors configurable so there is a combobox that says:

1. USA (which should color the fireworks red, white and blue)
2. St Patricks Day  (which should color the fireworks various shades of green . .
3. etc  . .

and i want it to look like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

the fireworks are all a single image right now and i would want to "intermingle" the selected color (so for #1 above, it shows red, white and blue all sitting side by side. (compared to the left side of the image is all blue, the right side is all red, etc.  .)

so i have an image and i have two choices:

1. Create a seperate image for every example in the dropdown.
2. See if there is a way to dynamically change colors of parts of an image within an html page
3. other suggestions ??

i wanted to get feedback on if #2 was possible or i should stick with #1.  obviously as the list gets longer, #1 becomes more annoying and #2 is more appealing (if its possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well my other suggestion would be to have the firework as a mask, inverted, and use an underlying background colour in the box that holds it.

That way you will get your colour tints however you like, with a single alpha-transparency image.

Comment: i have uploaded pictures as examples of what i want to produce.  can you clarify if your approach would be suitable given this ?

Comment: @ooo: You do not want to do that using images, the lag on the browser would be immense in most cases, use the `<canvas>` object and animate with it, or do it in Flash.

Comment: how would you do this in flash / canvas to change colors?

Comment: i am not trying to do any animation . .just replace the colors of the image

Comment: @ooo: So it is a fixed image? Ah, it would be very difficult to do the way we (Sotiris and I) suggested, as that assumes a single colour.  I would just pre-generate all possibilities, or write a script to generate it, if not previously produced.  With flash or canvas, I was talking about drawing/animating it, but as you just have a fixed image, it would not be worthwhile.  However you could use multiple layers in flash or the canvas with masks, to give the same effect.

Comment: thanks for your feedback.  Can you give me for insight to your statement about using "masks"?  any examples as i don't quite follow

Comment: @ooo: In flash? You have three coloured components to your image, if you separate them in to three images, black and transparency, then use them with solid colour backgrounds as you require with an appropriate [blend mode](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/UsingFlash/help.html?content=WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7d5b.html), you will get the components with the correct colour.  If the transparency is preserved, you can overlay them to get the graphic you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use png's transparency. Create the fireworks in way that the place you want to be changed to be transparent. Then wrap the image within a div, which will change its color using javascript.

A sample code is below using jQuery

```
$("#green").click(function() {
    $("div").css("background", "green")
});

$("#yellow").click(function() {
    $("div").css("background", "yellow")
});
```

**html**

```
<div><img src="path-to-image.png"></div>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/wyZnc/

Comment: i see how that works on a simple image but i have thousands of different fireworks that i have to color.  how would this scale? (see image on question)

Comment: from the moment you have to change the color using photoshop (or another program) just make the required parts transparent. Then you can modify the jQuery according the needs.

Comment: Isn't that what I said? Admittedly without a demo. ;-)

Comment: @Orbling lol, I misunderstood what you said. Well I don't think there is a shortest way to do this. Just instead create many different images for each firework, create a transparent png. With css and html I don't think you have another option.

Comment: @Soltris: For what he wants to achieve, I would never try it with HTML/CSS, too many objects in animation at once, following complex paths - the browsers would generally just not cope.  Flash or perhaps a canvas object would be the suggestions.  It could possibly be done with an animated GIF transparency using the model we've suggested.

Comment: @Orbling - i am NOT trying to do any animation.  just generate a picture